# Python regex to replace in a string

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace a part of a string and came accross re.sub.

```
import re
line = "-p ${config.tab} -sp"
rep = re.sub('-p(.*?)-sp', 'sam', line)
```

I expected the output would be:-

```
-p sam -sp
```

But its replacing all by sam and giving:-

```
sam
```

Any help?Thanks

Comment: you have a typo `line.sub` must be `re.sub` , you need to use look around !

Comment: Good spotted @Kasra. I changed that but giving me the same result. I think my regex is wrong

Comment: have a look http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem** with `-p(.*?)-sp`

The `-p` and `-sp` at the start and end is consumed by the regex engine. And `re.sub` repalces the entire string matched by the regex

That is http://regex101.com/r/oH3lV9/1

**Solution**

You can use look arounds

```
>>> rep = re.sub('(?<=-p )(.*?)(?= -sp)', 'sam', line)
>>> rep
'-p sam -sp'
```

- `(?<=-p )` asserts that the string is presceded by `-p` but not consumed it just check if it prescedes only
- `(?= -sp )` asserts  that the string is followed by `-sp`

See the difference http://regex101.com/r/oH3lV9/2

Answer (score 0):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) for capturing the characters in which you want to refer it later and you must need to define your pattern as raw string.

```
>>> line = "-p ${config.tab} -sp"
>>> print(re.sub(r'(-p\s)(.*?)(\s-sp)', r"\1sam\3", line))
-p sam -sp
>>> print(re.sub(r'(-p\s).*?(\s-sp)', r"\1sam\2", line))
-p sam -sp
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wT0zZ8/5)

**Explanation:**

- `(-p\s+)` Captures `-p` and the following one or more space characters.
- `.*?` Non-greedy match of any character zero or more times.
- `(\s+-sp)` captures one or more spaces and the following `-sp`
- Replacing all the matched characters with the characters inside group index 1 plus the string `sam` plus the characters inside group index 2 will give you the desired output.